# What type of insurance would protect you against the Amazon 1p bug?

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance, hobby-income

After seeing many hobby and small businesses losing thousands of pounds due to a software bug pricing their products at 1p on Amazon I've been wondering.

Is there a type of insurance that a hobby business or small company could take out to protect themselves against something like this?

Comment: Public Liability Insurance ?? Check here http://andrewminalto.com/insurance-for-ebay-sellers/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the appropriate recourse in this scenario is to bring a court case for breach of contract.   The 1p repricing issue has been admitted as an error out of scope of the purpose of the software.